# DIY EOG (Electrooculography) Circuitry Dangers?

Tags: amplifier, filter, biopotential

I wanted to try to build my own EOG filter and amplifier circuit. I've found many online sources that use an instrumentation amplifier, high pass and low pass filters, and additional amplifiers on the end, or a similar combination of those basic things.

However, I've been curious as to the safety aspect of this. I am not too experienced with hooking up hardware to the human body, so I am not sure what I need to look out for, or if it is even dangerous at all, since the probes should only be reading the information, and not delivering electricity to the body.

Others seems to have success with these designs. What could possibly go wrong? What should I look out for? And is it more recommended that I don't do this?

Answer (score 3):

I'd recommend A) use a battery, and B) before you put the electrodes across your eyes, place them someplace with less potential for damage, like your arm.  If it hurts on your arm, don't continue.

Use disposable pediatric ECG electrodes, if you can get them.

The safest course of action is to isolate the output before hooking it up to an oscilloscope, using something like an Avago HCNR200 (cheap, requires support circuitry) or an isolation amplifier (expensive, but easy), but if it doesn't hurt on your arm, you should be OK.

UPDATE:
Also, don't place the electrodes on somebody w/ implanted electronic devices.  Probably won't do anything, even worst case, but better to avoid the expensive risk of destroying a device.

Answer (score 1):

Successful connection of signal monitoring probes to the human body needs to be done with great care. If you operate battery type power supply with no mains power connectivity then it can be relatively safe as long as the voltage is kept low.

However if you make ANY connections, signal and/or power, to mains powered equipment then safety agency guidelines kick in big time. This will require that the probing and first stage amplifier circuitry needs to be isolated either by optical, transformer or other techniques. The transformer method is often used because the link can also be used to pass a small amount of power across the isolation barrier to source power for the sensor and/or amplifier circuitry.

Signals on the human body are extremely low level and can be found in conditions that vary over a large range of source impedance. Such situation usually leads to a LOT of stray pick of the AC power line frequency (50 or 60 Hz). Since many of the interesting body signals also cross the 50/60 Hz and 100/120 Hz frequency ranges  as well it is essential to add filtering to the detected signals. This is often done with switch capacitor type filters that offer very narrow notch characteristics at the power line frequency and its multiples.

Answer (score 1):

When I worked on EOG many years ago I used medically-rated isolation amplifiers and power supplies. They were rather expensive.

Unless you really know what you are doing, I'd forget about it.

Comment: I bought a 8A rated medical grade isolation transformer on e-bay for ~$70. On the other hand, you could still easily kill yourself with just the *isolated* side of the transformer. They protect you from ground loops, but not from stupid. If you don't know what you need to do to be safe, you need to do more reading.